# I can't import a class from a folder at another level

Tags: python, class, import

My directory hierarchy is:

```
myproject
    |
    |----classes
    |        |
    |        |----__init__.py
    |        |----myclasse.py
    |
    |----scripts
    |        |
    |        |----__init__.py
    |        |----main.py
```

I have attempted to import the method 'meth' from the class 'myclasse.py' into 'main.py as follows:

```
from ..classes.myclasse import meth
```

or

```
from ..classes import myclasse
from myclasse import meth
```

or

```
import ..classes.myclasse
from myclasse import meth
```

However, none of my attempts have been successful.

I have done my own research on similar questions, but I do not understand why this is not functioning as I would like.

Answer (score 4):

Add emply `__init__.py` as a file in folder myproject.
From `mail.py` issue

```
from myproject.classes.myclasse import meth
```

Comment: I’m at my wit’s end. With `__init__.py` in folder `myproject` and following the Python tutorial about packages 
https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#packages
it’s still not working. I get the message `ImportError: No module named 'myproject'`

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Alexey, here is some background reading, Section 6.4 in particular:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Also a personal experience: there are two underscores before and after __init__.py.